# Projectile not shooting direction of my weapon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bullet

So my game is sort of like a 3d top down shooter, so I want my gun to shoot wherever the mouse is and it wont go to the mouse unless im shooting down. If you've seen brackyes game called ball wars, im sort of trying to replicate one like that but the projectile is not shooting the right way.

I got my script from blackthornprods ranged combat tutorial (which is for 2d so maybe thats the issue but I dont know how to solve it) :

```cs
public float speed;
public float lifeTime;

private void Start()
{
    Invoke("DestoryProjectile", lifeTime);
}

private void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void DestroyProjectile()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Appreciate anyone to try!

Here is my other script: 
 Camera mainCam;

```
public GameObject projectile;

public Transform shotPoint;

private float timeBtwShots;
public float startTimeBtwShots;

void Awake()
{
    mainCam = Camera.main;
}

void Update()
{
    float objectDepthFromCamera = Vector3.Dot(
            transform.position - mainCam.transform.position,
            mainCam.transform.forward);

    Vector3 cursorWorldPosition = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition
            + Vector3.forward * objectDepthFromCamera);

    Vector3 localUpNeeded = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.forward,
            cursorWorldPosition - transform.position);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, localUpNeeded);

    if(timeBtwShots <= 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Instantiate(projectile, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
            timeBtwShots = startTimeBtwShots;
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        timeBtwShots -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add `Input.mousePosition` anywhere else on your code, or this is your entier projectile class ?

Comment: The problem is in the code spawning the bullet. We need that code.

Comment: I edited my question, u should find it there

Answer (score 1):

Projectile not shooting direction of my weapon. Simple solution -

- First instantiate or pool the instance of projectile.
- Set rotation of projection from the rotation of weapon & set location to spawn point
- Now fire, or whatever strategy you are using

Consider Global rotation, if you need help, tell me, I will edit and give a snippet of code.

*This should work.* If doesn't post all necessary code, I will give a better solution.

[Here](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Simple-Shooter) is sample github project I created, just for you. I opened Unity nearly after a year. Please check all the [versions](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Simple-Shooter/commits/master).

Must check :

```
firing in facing direction  
just instantiate at spawn point
just added some rotation
```

I think this should give you concept.

```
Press X for a rantom rotation
Press Space to shoot a projectile :lol:
The white cube shows that it always shoots at a constant direction
```

Comment: Since I am not sure how to do this since I started unity 2  months ago, I will edit my question and put the script the instantiates the projectile, can you please edit that and show me how to do what you are saying above

Comment: i will add a sample project, as soon as possible

Comment: @Moodie i have updated the answer and added github project link, don't forget to upvote and accept answer, you can mail me if encounter more problem...

Comment: Okay thank you I really appreciate it! I will chack it out soon!!

Comment: I actually dont really know how to use git hub, so can you can explain what im supposed to do with that link? Lol I feel stupid.

Comment: click on [this](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Simple-Shooter/archive/master.zip) link the project will be download, open in unity, try to learn from those codes, modify... there is a single file to control the gun..